# Redirect Sub-domain to Sub-directory (.Net Core App)

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following sub-domain:

> http://myapp.example.com

I have an application startpoint for a **.Net Core 3.0** app on a shared **Windows server** at the following path from the domain root:

> /myapp

I've modified the web.config in my domain's root directory as follows to be able to reach the application via the subdomain (myapp.example.com):

```
<rule name="myapp.example.com Rewrite" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^\/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*myapp\.example\.com.*" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/myapp/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

While the application homepage loads fine initially, when I make any requests in my application, the URL displays as follows:

> http://myapp.example.com/myapp/{app routing}

**How would I remove the "myapp/" subdirectory path from the URL?**

I figure the required change should be made in one of the following locations:

1. Domain root web.config
2. Startup.cs in MyApp using URL Rewriting Middleware
3. XML file imported with URL Rewriting Middleware in Startup.cs of MyApp.

Comment: You need a full reverse proxy setup, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing, not merely a few rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks. Why will rewrite rules not work? (My hosting provider does not enable ARR on IIS, so this all may not be possible after all.) I would gladly mark an answer explaining why rewrite doesn't work here.

Comment: Merely using URL Rewrite module should require your web app to cooperate friendly. "when I make any requests in my application, the URL displays as follows" seems to indicate that your web app issues its own redirection to modify URLs (as IIS URL Rewrite with Rewrite action does not change URLs), which must be investigated and resolved (like changing source code). You should avoid "URL Rewriting Middleware" for a while, as it only makes the situation more complex to analyze.